# How can I export my model as an FBX file and have my model be one complete piece and not multiple pieces?

Tags: modeling, objects, export, .fbx

I am stuck, ive tried more than a few things now to get this to work but i am unable to do so.  After this i will be continuing to try and find a few more solutions anyways my model is pretty simple and its basically a panel/wall and it is made from a plane which  i then loop cut, applied a mirror modifier, added some cubes, cylinders, used a couple of addons (jmesh specifically), shaded smooth, applied scale, some shading, thought i was doing pretty good then when i got to export it exports as multiple pieces.  ive tried a few things selecting all of the objects and object - relations - make single user - object and data and that seems to screw everything up, ive tried joining the objects and that also screws everything up but in a totally different way.  Im sure a lot of this is unnecessary information but i am just trying to give some details in case it does as I am just starting out with blender.  Any help would be great. I appreciate you taking the time, thanks for reading and enjoy the rest of your day/night!!

---

Wow thank you all so much for the responses!! Ive uploaded the blend file on blend exchange, it is no where near 30 MB, i am sure that an experienced user will be able to look at it and figure out what is going on with it, i am sure its easier to do it that way then to take a bunch of screen shots and attempting to explain things that i am trying to figure out myself.  i appreciate the help very much, if your able to take a look at it and let me know what ive done wrong or need to do to be able to export the model as a single object that would be so amazing.  i probably did something at the very start that i shouldnt have done and thats fine if thats the case, i will start over and do it all again if i know what ive done to not be able to to export it.

Thank you so much for all of the information and taking the time to respond!!!

Here is the file:

[image]

Comment: Without any images or seeing your Blend file, it's impossible to guess what's going on. If it's smaller than 30Meg, you can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it. You can also take screenshots of your scene and settings via Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu then edit your question here and add your images into it.

Comment: You can join objects, but if they use different modifiers to get their final shape, joining can result in losing modifier effects or adding them to parts which did not have a modifier before. To join them without having everything "screwed up", you have to apply the modifiers first... you wrote above you "applied a mirror modifier", but I guess you just added it to objects. To apply a modifier means converting the modified mesh permanently to the modified shape and then the modifier gets automatically removed. You can apply modifiers from their menu, or Ctrl+A when hovering the mouse over it.

Comment: This post would be a bit easier to read if your restricyed it to the current facts: what you've got, what you want, and the difference. It does sound as if you need to join your objects without messing them up. That means applying modifiers, as Gordon has explained.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is select all objects by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> in the viewport. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Visual Geometry to Mesh* to apply all modifiers on all objects at once.

[image: apply visual geometry to mesh]

Now that they are still all selected you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them without messing up the mesh. Only the shading looks a bit weird now, because everything is shaded smooth. To change that, right-click and choose *Shade Auto Smooth*.

This applying and joining is a destructive workflow, so make sure you have saved the original object if you ever want to change something. I would also recommend to delete all objects that are made invisible before export to make sure you don't export anything you don't want to - although in the export options there is *Include* > *Limit To* > *Selected Only* and *Visible Only*, so you don't necessarily have to delete those other objects.