# What would cause this when importing into unreal engine?

Tags: export, import, .fbx

When I import my model into unreal engine there is a "hole" or a "slice" that is missing from my model.  For some more information on the model I am working with you can check here:

[How can I export my model as an FBX file and have my model be one complete piece and not multiple pieces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/303158/how-can-i-export-my-model-as-an-fbx-file-and-have-my-model-be-one-complete-piece)

As for what is currently happening

https://imageupload.io/12eBIqdsMZp9G5x

Comment: You can add images directly into your post instead of linking some external site. Also it would be good to add some markers in your image to point people to what you are talking about. And it would be nice if you upload in this question the model you prepared for export instead of linking to the unprepared model in the other question.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.